# How to use custom objects in xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

How do I add an existing custom UIView class to the custom objects dialog? I can't seem to be able to reuse the custom XIBs that I have created earlier without physically copying them from one XIB to another. Shouldn't this supposed to be automatic?

Below is a screenshot of the custom objects dialog. It's always empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution to your problem per se, but it will let you use your custom UIView sub-classes in other NIBs.

What I do is I just drag a regular UIView instance on to the drawing board, and then I open the Utilities pane (the pane that appears on the far right), and then the Identity Inspector (Third icon along), and at the very top there is a section labeled "Custom Class". I simply change the "Class" attribute in there to the name of my sub-class.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am doing. I'm just wondering whether XCode actually provides support for this through the custom class tab, as it suggests that we may be able to drag and drop custom objects in the future.